# How do I know if the Bitcoin Core software on my computer is running taproot, segwit or something else?

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, taproot

I would like to check this.

I imagine there must be some command to verify the current version of node software Bitcoin I am running ('version' is probably not the correct name here. Maybe 'soft fork' is?), e.g. Segwit, Taproot, etc.

Comment: There are version numbers e.g. 0.16, 0.17...., 22.0, 23.0 and soft forks are only active on certain versions e.g. Taproot is only active on 0.21.1 and later versions. The zero was dropped from 22.0 onwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until Bitcoin Core 23.0.0, the status of deployments of consensus changes can be listed with the [`getblockchaininfo`](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getblockchaininfo.html) command:

> Returns an object containing various state info regarding blockchain
> processing.
>
> ### Result
>
> ```
> {                                         (json object)
>   "chain" : "str",                        (string) current network name (main, test, regtest)
>   "blocks" : n,                           (numeric) the height of the most-work fully-validated chain. The genesis block has height 0
>   "headers" : n,                          (numeric) the current number of headers we have validated
>   "bestblockhash" : "str",                (string) the hash of the currently best block
>   "difficulty" : n,                       (numeric) the current difficulty
>   "mediantime" : n,                       (numeric) median time for the current best block
>   "verificationprogress" : n,             (numeric) estimate of verification progress [0..1]
>   "initialblockdownload" : true|false,    (boolean) (debug information) estimate of whether this node is in Initial Block Download mode
>   "chainwork" : "hex",                    (string) total amount of work in active chain, in hexadecimal
>   "size_on_disk" : n,                     (numeric) the estimated size of the block and undo files on disk
>   "pruned" : true|false,                  (boolean) if the blocks are subject to pruning
>   "pruneheight" : n,                      (numeric) lowest-height complete block stored (only present if pruning is enabled)
>   "automatic_pruning" : true|false,       (boolean) whether automatic pruning is enabled (only present if pruning is enabled)
>   "prune_target_size" : n,                (numeric) the target size used by pruning (only present if automatic pruning is enabled)
>   "softforks" : {                         (json object) status of softforks
>     "xxxx" : {                            (json object) name of the softfork
>       "type" : "str",                     (string) one of "buried", "bip9"
>       "bip9" : {                          (json object) status of bip9 softforks (only for "bip9" type)
>         "status" : "str",                 (string) one of "defined", "started", "locked_in", "active", "failed"
>         "bit" : n,                        (numeric) the bit (0-28) in the block version field used to signal this softfork (only for "started" status)
>         "start_time" : xxx,               (numeric) the minimum median time past of a block at which the bit gains its meaning
>         "timeout" : xxx,                  (numeric) the median time past of a block at which the deployment is considered failed if not yet locked in
>         "since" : n,                      (numeric) height of the first block to which the status applies
>         "statistics" : {                  (json object) numeric statistics about BIP9 signalling for a softfork (only for "started" status)
>           "period" : n,                   (numeric) the length in blocks of the BIP9 signalling period
>           "threshold" : n,                (numeric) the number of blocks with the version bit set required to activate the feature
>           "elapsed" : n,                  (numeric) the number of blocks elapsed since the beginning of the current period
>           "count" : n,                    (numeric) the number of blocks with the version bit set in the current period
>           "possible" : true|false         (boolean) returns false if there are not enough blocks left in this period to pass activation threshold
>         }
>       },
>       "height" : n,                       (numeric) height of the first block which the rules are or will be enforced (only for "buried" type, or "bip9" type with "active" status)
>       "active" : true|false               (boolean) true if the rules are enforced for the mempool and the next block
>     },
>     ...
>   },
>   "warnings" : "str"                      (string) any network and blockchain warnings
> }
> ```

In Bitcoin Core 23.0.0 this was moved into the `getdeploymentinfo` command:

> Returns an object containing various state info regarding deployments of consensus changes.
>
> ### Result
>
> ```
> {                                       (json object)
>   "hash" : "str",                       (string) requested block hash (or tip)
>   "height" : n,                         (numeric) requested block height (or tip)
>   "deployments" : {                     (json object)
>     "xxxx" : {                          (json object) name of the deployment
>       "type" : "str",                   (string) one of "buried", "bip9"
>       "height" : n,                     (numeric, optional) height of the first block which the rules are or will be enforced (only for "buried" type, or "bip9" type with "active" status)
>       "active" : true|false,            (boolean) true if the rules are enforced for the mempool and the next block
>       "bip9" : {                        (json object, optional) status of bip9 softforks (only for "bip9" type)
>         "bit" : n,                      (numeric, optional) the bit (0-28) in the block version field used to signal this softfork (only for "started" and "locked_in" status)
>         "start_time" : xxx,             (numeric) the minimum median time past of a block at which the bit gains its meaning
>         "timeout" : xxx,                (numeric) the median time past of a block at which the deployment is considered failed if not yet locked in
>         "min_activation_height" : n,    (numeric) minimum height of blocks for which the rules may be enforced
>         "status" : "str",               (string) status of deployment at specified block (one of "defined", "started", "locked_in", "active", "failed")
>         "since" : n,                    (numeric) height of the first block to which the status applies
>         "status_next" : "str",          (string) status of deployment at the next block
>         "statistics" : {                (json object, optional) numeric statistics about signalling for a softfork (only for "started" and "locked_in" status)
>           "period" : n,                 (numeric) the length in blocks of the signalling period
>           "threshold" : n,              (numeric, optional) the number of blocks with the version bit set required to activate the feature (only for "started" status)
>           "elapsed" : n,                (numeric) the number of blocks elapsed since the beginning of the current period
>           "count" : n,                  (numeric) the number of blocks with the version bit set in the current period
>           "possible" : true|false       (boolean, optional) returns false if there are not enough blocks left in this period to pass activation threshold (only for "started" status)
>         },
>         "signalling" : "str"            (string) indicates blocks that signalled with a # and blocks that did not with a -
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Example output of `getdeploymentinfo`:

```
{
  "hash": "00000000000000000009bd5a8aa82361c8daca42d241d0b1606d357579af35c5",
  "height": 732670,
  "deployments": {
    "bip34": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": true,
      "height": 227931
    },
    "bip66": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": true,
      "height": 363725
    },
    "bip65": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": true,
      "height": 388381
    },
    "csv": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": true,
      "height": 419328
    },
    "segwit": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": true,
      "height": 481824
    },
    "taproot": {
      "type": "bip9",
      "height": 709632,
      "active": true,
      "bip9": {
        "start_time": 1619222400,
        "timeout": 1628640000,
        "min_activation_height": 709632,
        "status": "active",
        "since": 709632,
        "status_next": "active"
      }
    }
  }
}
```